# Lucene learning difficulty

Tags: lucene

Recently `Solr` & `Lucene` is used in projects that I involved, when try to understanding `Lucene`'s mechanism, I refer to `Lucene in action 2nd` and `Lucene`'s source code (*v5.3*), the book is out of data, and the source code is quite complex.

I'd like to understand the data structure & algorithms used by lucene, and its cache mechanisms.

So, I am wondering what do you refer to when learning about searching base on `Lucene`. Hope new version of `Lucene in action` could be written.

Comment: Start with [the demo](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/demo/index.html).

Comment: I think the book still describes the structure of the Lucene index well enough. The [Javadocs](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene53/package-summary.html) should also help you.

Comment: @user1071777 The book is great, I am reading it, even thought a lot of API changed, even some mechanism changed. I am wondering why new version of the book is not written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best entry point for Lucene is the **[main documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/)** page.

The **[JavaDoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/index.html)** is really useful because well documented and up to date.

You may then discover the internal mechanisms by practicing the **[small Java code](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/demo/overview-summary.html#overview_description)**.

Here are the documentation about **[scoring mechanisms](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#package_description)** like Vector Space Model or BM25.

The **[file format](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene54/package-summary.html#package_description)** is well described too and up to date.

*P.S.: I was not able to find a "latest" link. This answer may be updated when Lucene's version change.*

Comment: The link about `file format` is very useful, to me! I didn't saw that in `<Lucene in action 2nd>`